# Android Browser - prevent zoom effect on Double Click (tap) on background

Tags: zooming, double-click, android-browser

In my mobile webpage I use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
```

but in the Android Browser when I double-tap the background, the screen still tries to zoom (triggers some kind of bubble-effect, that zooms in for a very short time and then returns to the normal size).

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? 
Since the webpage is a game, I just need to disable all zooming.

Comment: Did you ever find the solution for this?  I am struggling with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting user-scalable to *no* instead of *0*:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Comment: Tried that, and makes no difference. It still zooms a little and then gets back to its original state.